# MongoDB - Grandes coleções de documentos

Tags: mongodb

Estou desenvolvendo um site onde os usuários poderão votar a favor ou contra locais que eles conhecem. Para fazer isso eu poderia criar uma coleção chamava "votos" relacionando o local com o usuário e se foi a favor ou contra, o problema é que isso pode gerar uma enorme coleção de documentos, outra solução seria o documento de usuário ter um array com seus votos assim eu separaria a coleção de votos nos usuários. Qual é a melhor abordagem para essa situação em questão de performance

Comment: Não seria melhor gravar os votos no documento do local? Normalmente os votos são exibidos ao exibir o local, ou seja, ao exibir um local, se você salvar os votos nos usuários, terá que percorrer cada usuário para encontrar os votos do local.

Comment: Cara, não sei a quantidade de informação que você vai gravar em cada documento, mas o utilizador pode ter N votos e isso significa que o documento pode crescer sem controle. Isso é ruim porque o documento é limitado a 16MB.

Comment: Em relação ao acesso aos dados, o melhor seria ter uma nova coleção chamada votos, dai tanto os usuário como o local poderiam buscar seus votos sem esforço. A minha preocupação é com o tamanho da collection, qual será o tamanho máximo recomendado para uma collection? @FilipeMoraes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Particularmente, creio que a melhor solução seria "desnormalizar".

Deixar dois campos no documento do local (um com a quantidade de votos positivos, e a outra com negativos) e uma outra collection de votos, sumarizando local + voto + pessoa.

Dessa forma, caso voce precisa listar os locais, ja tem a informação de votos por local (sem precisar juntar outras collections), e tem a informação propriamente dita na collection de votos, caso precise buscar especificos por pessoa.

Comment: Obrigado, desenvolvi desta forma